# How can I change the drop shadow of a node?

Tags: node-editor, interface, customization, theme

I think I just tried every setting I could find, but I can't solve the puzzle:

All the colors of the nodes can be changed in the *Blender Preferences* under *Themes*, just not the shadow cast of the nodes.

Am I missing something? How can I change the shadow intensity?

[image]

...Or is the shadow actually hardcoded?